# What's the best Django search app?

Tags: python, django, search, search-engine

I'm building a Django project that needs search functionality, and until there's a `django.contrib.search`, I have to choose a search app. So, which is the best? By "best" I mean...

- easy to install / set up
- has a Django- or at least Python-friendly API
- can perform reasonably complex searches

Here are some apps I've heard of, please suggest others if you know of any:

- [djangosearch](http://code.google.com/p/djangosearch/)
- [django-sphinx](http://code.google.com/p/django-sphinx/)

I'd also like to avoid using a third-party search engine (like Google SiteSearch), because some of the data I'd like to index is for site members only and should not be public.

Comment: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/search/

Comment: Normally things like "best" are pretty subjective, but django really does have one "best" search app as the accepted answer shows.

Comment: Unless I totally misunderstand django, this is still a library request and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Check out [Haystack Search](http://haystacksearch.org/) - a new model based search abstraction layer that currently supports [Xapian](http://xapian.org/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Whoosh](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home). Looks like it's well supported and documented.

Comment: Haystack is under active development and the author is always available via the email list.

Comment: From djangosearch project: "This project is no longer under active development. If you're looking for a django full text search application that works with multiple search engines, check out haystack. If you're looking for something specific to Solr, you might want to try solango. "

Comment: Haystack has been badly, if at all, supported for quite some time. I recommend you avoid it at this point. Maybe they will fix it in the future but its in a bad place now.

Comment: I agree, the latest version of haystack (2.1) is not working at all with my python 2.7 version of django 1.4.

Answer (score 19):

Justin, I'd try [djangosearch](http://code.google.com/p/djangosearch/) first: Jacob Kaplan-Moss (Django's lead developer) is working on it.

Potential hazards:

- The home page warns the API might not be entirely stable

Potential benefits:

- “The long term goal is for this to become `django.contrib.search`.”

Comment: The page now says "This project is no longer under active development. If you're looking for a django full text search application that works with multiple search engines, check out Haystack."

Answer (score 18):

I am searching for the same thing, as are a lot of other people. Let's hope that *django.contrib.search* will be added soon.

In the meantime, this is what I found:

- http://code.google.com/p/djangosearch/
- http://code.google.com/p/django-sphinx/
- http://code.google.com/p/djapian/
- http://code.google.com/p/django-search-lucene/
- http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/

To me, most look quite complicated and, frankly, a little daunting to implement.
I'd be interested to learn what you think of these.

Answer (score 9):

The google code page for [djangosearch](http://code.google.com/p/djangosearch/) indicates that it is no longer under active development, and suggests [haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) or [solango](http://code.google.com/p/django-solr-search/).

Comment: Solango says it is no longer under development and recommends the use of Haystack.

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend Sphinx for full-text search and aggregation, and django-sphinx is good enough for production use.  We found that Sphinx was the least resource-intensive and fastest way to index and search our documents and that django-sphinx was a nice wrapper on top of the sphinx client.

The group by aggregation is particularly nice, if for example you want to display how many documents with a certain tag or by a certain author (or both) matched a search.  In memory attribute updates were convenient too, especially for removing deleted articles immediately.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Garth. I had seen that djangosearch wanted to become the official Django search, but I was hesitant to use it because I couldn't find any documentation! Luckily, there's a [README in subversion](http://code.google.com/p/djangosearch/source/browse/branches/soc-new-backends/doc/README.txt) that I hadn't seen before, and it makes the API look very cool:

```
# set up the model
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
    is_outdoors = models.BooleanField()

    index = djangosearch.ModelIndex(text=['title'], 
                                    additional=['date', 'is_outdoors'])

# run a search
results = Event.index.search("django conference")
```

Answer (score 6):

I just needed a **very quick** solution that was no-fuss for an internal app.

I found the article [Adding search to Django in a snap](http://julienphalip.com/post/2825034077/adding-search-to-a-django-site-in-a-snap), and that worked splendid for me!

Obviously it lacks the speed, scalability and features of the real projects like Haystack, but this one is easier to set up, and I don't really need anything else than keyword AND-search.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider letting Yahoo do all the hard work with their Build your own Search Service (BOSS).  Here is a great blog post that walks you through the process:
http://www.peterkrantz.com/2008/yahoo-search-in-django/

Comment: I've got a Django package that makes it even easier: https://bitbucket.org/jaap3/django-bosssearch/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like everyone here missed [django-xappy](https://launchpad.net/django-xappy)

After quick evaluation of all existing search addons for Django, I found this one as most flexible and easiest to use. It's rough on the edges in few places, but it's still the best way to use power of [Xapian](http://xapian.org) search engine inside Django projects.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [Django Solr search](http://code.google.com/p/django-solr-search/) (aka "Solango") which comes with some nice documentation to get you started...

Answer (score 1):

If you have large amount of data to be indexed or you expect high traffic, I'd suggest using some external search engine, like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). This way, you'll keep *shared-nothing* approach and be able to scale your site components independently.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am going to have to give a shout out to Djapian.

It is rock-solid...just pull down a source distribution and peek inside. Top notch code, not very many comments tho..

It's still a young software project, but I think the django community should throw it's weight behind this one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joe,

We decided to go with Tsearch2 and a custom postgres adaptor. Tsearch2 does not need an extra process to run, which was convenient since we are on a WebFaction hosting with limited  memory... It's not completely done yet, but seems to be a good solution...

Answer (score 0):

I found [Djoosh](http://github.com/idangazit/djoosh/tree/master) which relies on the pure-python external search engine [Whoosh](http://whoosh.ca/) to work well with my 'Python' brain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a 3rd party search engine I can recommend [Yahoo BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/) and [django-bosssearch](https://bitbucket.org/jaap3/django-bosssearch/).

Yahoo BOSS is a paid service, but it saves you setting up and maintaining other search software on your server.