# the best search engine written with python

Tags: python, django, search-engine

i want to build an information support system which is an web app.
and we gonna use Django as the frame,but i don't know which search engine to use ?
can you give me some suggestions on the search engine which we can use in our project,it must be written with python.
thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056/whats-the-best-django-search-app

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you'd be happy with [whoosh](http://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home), possibly "fronted" by [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) which is a neat way to support any of several search engines in Django (but the other underlying engines it supports are not "pure Python"... `whoosh` *is*).

I believe both whoosh and haystack support Unicode, so, in particular, Chinese too.

Answer (score 1):

[Xapian](http://www.xapian.org) with the Python bindings is the best solution for Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for Performance , Try Sphinx Search : http://sphinxsearch.com/ , best known highest performance /highly stable search engine and it have easy to use python API.
But please note it is  Search engine for MySQL *You have to parse files and import them to database yourself.