# Django: get related content

Tags: django

my question is how I can obtain related content, as does StackOverflow with questions with similar titles. In my case, no tags, just a textarea.

There is something already done in Django for this? or how I can do it?

I think I can use sphinx for searching and get related content, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best Django search app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056/whats-the-best-django-search-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into django-haystack. it deals with full-text search and finding relevant results.